Dudas con la importación de datos de Mysql a Excel
Muy buenas amigos de la comunidad, estoy realizando la importación de datos de mysql a excel, lo primero es presentarles la planilla que utilizo para dicho proceso:

miren he realizado las pruebas para en este caso para datos menores a 12 filas las cuales me funcionan muy bien sin problema alguno, pero hago las pruebas para traer los datos con el código a través de php con mas de 12 filas me da problemas, este es el código que utilizo actualmente:
<?php
// Incluir la librería PHPSpreadsheet
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

// Datos de conexión a la base de datos
$server = "localhost";
$username = "hector";
$password = "";
$database = "oficina";

// Crear conexión
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

// Comprobar conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Obtener el número de siniestro desde la URL
$n_siniestro = $_GET['n_siniestro'];

// Consultas para obtener los datos
$sqlAjuste = "SELECT * FROM ajuste WHERE N_Siniestro = '$n_siniestro'";
$sqlAjuste1 = "SELECT * FROM ajuste1 WHERE N_Siniestro = '$n_siniestro'";
$sqlAjuste2 = "SELECT * FROM ajuste2 WHERE N_Siniestro = '$n_siniestro'";
$sqlAjuste4 = "SELECT * FROM ajuste4 WHERE N_Siniestro = '$n_siniestro'";

$resultAjuste = $conn->query($sqlAjuste);
$resultAjuste1 = $conn->query($sqlAjuste1);
$resultAjuste2 = $conn->query($sqlAjuste2);
$resultAjuste4 = $conn->query($sqlAjuste4);

// Cargar la plantilla de Excel
$templateFile = 'ajuste.xlsx'; // Ruta a tu plantilla de Excel
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($templateFile);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Verificar y escribir datos de "ajuste"
if ($resultAjuste->num_rows > 0) {
    $dataAjuste = $resultAjuste->fetch_assoc();
    $sheet->setCellValue('E1', $dataAjuste['Nombre_Asegurado']); // Ajustar celdas según los datos de la tabla "ajuste"
    $sheet->setCellValue('E2', $dataAjuste['N_Siniestro']);
    $sheet->setCellValue('E4', $dataAjuste['Vehiculo_Asegurado']);
    $sheet->setCellValue('I4', $dataAjuste['Patente_Vehiculo']);
    $sheet->setCellValue('K4', $dataAjuste['Año_Vehiculo']);
}

$row = 9; // Asegúrate de que el inicio es la fila 9 para ambos "ajuste1" y "ajuste2"
// Verificar y escribir datos de "ajuste1" (Repuestos)
if ($resultAjuste1->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($dataAjuste1 = $resultAjuste1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $dataAjuste1['N_Filas']); // Ajustar según la plantilla
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $dataAjuste1['Repuestos']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $dataAjuste1['Ptotal_Repuestos']);
        $row++;
    }
}

// Verificar y escribir datos de "ajuste2" (Totales de repuestos)
$row = 9;
if ($resultAjuste2->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($dataAjuste2 = $resultAjuste2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $row, $dataAjuste2['Cantidad']); // Ajustar según la plantilla
        $sheet->setCellValue('H' . $row, $dataAjuste2['Punit_Repuestos']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $row, $dataAjuste2['Ptotal_Repuestos']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('J' . $row, $dataAjuste2['Descuento']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $row, $dataAjuste2['Precio_Total']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('L' . $row, $dataAjuste2['Observacion']);
        $row++;
    }
}

// Establecer la posición correcta para los subtotales y totales después de ingresar los repuestos
$rowTotal = $row;
$rowTotal++;
// Verificar y escribir subtotales y totales de repuestos
if ($resultAjuste->num_rows > 0) {
    $dataAjuste = $resultAjuste->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos1'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos1']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Total_Repuestos'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Total_Repuestos']);
    }
}

// Calcular la fila inicial para "Mano de obra"
$rowManoDeObra = $row;
// Verificar y escribir datos de "ajuste4" (Mano de obra)
if ($resultAjuste4->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $rowManoDeObra; // Fila inicial para mano de obra, ajustar según la plantilla
    while ($dataAjuste4 = $resultAjuste4->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Aseguramos que se maneje como texto
        $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('A' . $row, $dataAjuste4['N_Filas'], \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Detalle_Mobra']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Valor_Mobra']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Unidad']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Cantidad']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('H' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Precio_Mobra']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Subtotal']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('J' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Depreciacion']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Total_Mobra']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('L' . $row, $dataAjuste4['Observacion']);
        $row++;
    }
}

$rowTotal = $row; // Posición después de la última fila de repuestos
if ($resultAjuste->num_rows > 0) {
    $dataAjuste = $resultAjuste->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Mobra'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Mobra']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Mobra1'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Mobra1']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Total_Mobra'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Total_Mobra']);
    }
    $rowTotal++; // Incrementar fila después de mano de obra

    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Ajustado'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Ajustado']);
    }
    $rowTotal++; // Incrementar fila después de subtotal

    if (isset($dataAjuste['Deducible'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Deducible']);
        $valorDeducibleNegativo = $dataAjuste['Valor_Deducible'] * -1;
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $valorDeducibleNegativo);
    }
    $rowTotal++; // Incrementar fila después de deducible

    if (isset($dataAjuste['Total_Ajustado'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Total_Ajustado']);
    }
    $rowTotal += 2; // Incrementar fila después de total ajustado

    if (isset($dataAjuste['Equivalencia_UF'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Equivalencia_UF']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Perdida_UF'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Perdida_UF']);
    }
    $rowTotal++; // Incrementar fila después de equivalencia y pérdida UF

    if (isset($dataAjuste['Fecha_UF'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Fecha_UF']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Valor_UF'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Valor_UF']);
    }

    // Verificar si 'Observaciones' existe y no es nula
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Observaciones']) && !is_null($dataAjuste['Observaciones'])) {
        preg_match_all('/(\d+\.\-.*?)(?=\d+\.\-|$)/s', $dataAjuste['Observaciones'], $observaciones); 
        $rowObservaciones = $rowTotal + 2; // Incrementar fila después de valor UF 
        foreach ($observaciones[0] as $observacion) { 
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rowObservaciones, trim($observacion)); 
            $rowObservaciones++;
        }
    }
}

// Guardar el archivo Excel con los datos rellenados
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$file = 'cuadro_ajuste_' . $n_siniestro . '.xlsx';
$writer->save($file);
echo "Archivo Excel generado: <a href='$file'>Descargar</a>";
// Cerrar la conexión
$conn->close();
?>

y al momento de ejecutarlo a través de la web http://localhost/excel/exportar_ajuste.php?n_siniestro=398454863 me da este resultado:

si se dan cuenta en la línea 13, según la imagen anterior se encuentra el subtotal y los totales de los repuestos, por lo cual este debería desplazarse hacia abajo y según código debería estar funcionando, pero no se en donde esta el error del procedimiento, el error de docho proceso debe estar en esta parte del código:
// Establecer la posición correcta para los subtotales y totales después de ingresar los repuestos
$rowTotal = $row;
$rowTotal++;
// Verificar y escribir subtotales y totales de repuestos
if ($resultAjuste->num_rows > 0) {
    $dataAjuste = $resultAjuste->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos1'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Subtotal_Repuestos1']);
    }
    if (isset($dataAjuste['Total_Repuestos'])) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $rowTotal, $dataAjuste['Total_Repuestos']);
    }
}

en donde row(); lo rescato desde el proceso anterior y donde lo traspaso a $rowTotal y a este mismo le agrego una mas $rowTotal++;, para que me agregue en dicha línea el valor del subtotal y de los totales de los repuestos, favor de ayudarme llevo varios días en esto y no he podido solucionarlo, desde ya muchas gracias.

as intentado crear un arreglo o variables con los totales y simplemente escribirlo al final de toda la funcion? con un contador puedes saber cuantas filas se ingresaron y donde deben ir los totales....

@Bryromuy buenas te comento que si ves el código se encuentra lo que tu mencionas en donde row se traspasa a rowtotal y a la cual se le incrementa en +1 por lo cual esta solucionado eso, ahora ,lo que tu me dices de un arreglo, soy un novato en estas lides y estor aprendiendo a su vez, a que te refieres con un arreglo o variables con los totales si te puedes hacer con código, desde ya muchas gracias
